# $\deg(fg) \leq \deg(f)+\deg(g)$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

I'm trying to give a formal proof for the fact that given a commutative ring with one $R$, any pair of elements of the polynomial ring in $n>1$ variables $f, g \in R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]=\{ f : 
\mathbb{N}^n \to R \mid f(s_1,\ldots,s_n) \neq 0 \text{ only for a finite number of $n$-tuples }  (s_1,\ldots,s_n) \in \mathbb{N}^n\}$ satisfies that $\deg(fg) \leq \deg(f)+\deg(g)$ where $\deg(f) = \max(\{ s_1+\cdots+s_n \in \mathbb{N} \mid f(s_1,\ldots,s_n) \neq 0 \})$

The main problem that I find to generalize the idea in one variable is that the degree is natural number but $f$ and $g$ take a $n$-tuple as argument so this makes a lot harder to calculate $fg$. I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Show the claim for monomials
2. Show that $\deg(f+g)\le \max\{\deg f,\deg g\}$
3. Conclude